# Kendo Scheduler change today's cell background color in month view

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I need to change the background color of the current date cell in of a Kendo Scheduler in month view.

I have looked through their documentation, but have not found any related topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. It is actually very simple. Just use the following code in css:

```
.k-scheduler .k-today {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```